# Cannot change EditText in onCreateView

Tags: android

I want to reset my textinput everytime my fragment gets invoked.

This is the end of my onCreateView-method:

```
    txtValue.setText("");
    Log.d("debug", "Hello");

    txtValue.addTextChangedListener(tx);
    tx.onTextChanged(txtValue.getText(), 0, 0, 0);      

    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.toggleSoftInput(0, 0);
```

I get Hello everytime but the text never changes.

Comment: So after you call `txtValue.setText("")`, the EditText still has its previous value? I'm not sure what you're trying to do/show in your last 4 lines.

Comment: i am not sure but try onResume() and set your text in resume state. but there is a way to do it look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298399/same-fragments-edittext-and-requestfocus-issue

Comment: Yes that is the problem.. I just want to reset the input field so that it is empty.

Comment: what happened now ??? your problem should solved now after see the previous  answer ???

Comment: No I just mentioned that the problem is that I CANNOT reset my input.

Comment: so u have nth. now :) 0 problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience - it is very likely that it is caused by your instantiation.

Is your txtValue local and reassigned every time the setText is called? If yes - move it to a global object, it is likely that you are instantiating it more than once and that is causing your setText malfunction.

Also, are you sure that your onCreate method gets called? Do you always get that log output? In general, it is a good practice to separate gui object instantiations in a method invoked in your onCreate method and call the manipulations in onResume.

Comment: Hey thanks.. yes I am sure, since I always get the Hello like mentioned.
Also I am doing this before:
txtValue = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.txtValue);
txtValue is global but can this be the problem?

Comment: Then global/instantiation should be the problem. 
What about this "v" in your "v.findViewById", what is it? If you are inside the activity, you can remove it.
Also - is it possible that you have more than one TextView with that "txtValue" name in any of your layouts?

Comment: sorry, made a mistake - *shouldn't be
Did you pinpoint the reason for the and resolve it?